# Pythons global variable

Tags: python, pyqt, global-variables

How can I define a global variable.

For example I have Foo1 class and Foo2 class and I want to use FooVariable in this classes as a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted a global variable named `foo`, you would just have to put `global foo` at the top of any function in which it is used. For example,

```
def do_something():
    global foo
    foo = foo + 1
    print foo
```

Note that Python "global" variables are only global to the module they appear in, not global to the entire program (as in some languages).